# how to set image style based on role?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

Hi I have 100s of images on my site.

I have an image style which displays all of my photos at high quality. I have another image style which displays my images low quality with watermarks on them.

What I would like is if the user anonymous of a certain role all images will be of low quality and with watermarks. If the user is of a different role or a site admin they view all images at original/high quality.

I dont even know where to begin with this.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should track the DIV for that block where these image are coming.

Put the condition in the code checking the user privilege and apply the DIV appropriate to that. I have done something like it for a project long ago.